# In Vue.js, how do I access a function within a single file component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In Vue.js, I have created a single file component called Password.vue which contains two password fields, and associated checking.

First, I define my HTML within `<template></template>` tags and this works correctly.

Then, I define my JavaScript code as follows:

```
<script>

    computed: {
        passwordsValid() {

           // Password checking code here
        }
    },

};
</script>
```

I then have a signup function which imports `Password.vue`:

```
import PasswordComponent from "../components/Password.vue";
```

And then in my `signup.html` file, I have

```
<password-component></password-component>
```

To use the actual password component.

My issue is, my `passwordsValid` function is contained inside `Password.vue` and I can't access it from my `signup.html` file.

How can I do this? In other words, how can I access functions within a single file component?

Answer (score 0):

Create props for Password.vue:

```
props: {
  requestCheckPassword: Boolean,
}
```

Add watch:

```
watch: {
  requestCheckPassword () {
    this.$emit('passwordResult', {isValid: this.passwordsValid})
    this.$emit('update:requestCheckPassword', false)
  }
}
```

And then in signup.html file:

```
<password-component @passwordResult="methodFromMethodsSection" :request-check-password.sync="requestCheckPassword"></password-component>
```

And the last, in signup.html add:

```
data () {
  return {
    requestCheckPassword: false
  }
},
methods: {
  methodFromMethodsSection ({ isValid }) {
    // your logic, you can access isValid
  }
}
```

If you want to get the password check result, simply change the `requestCheckPassword` from data. For example:

```
<button @click="requestCheckPassword = true">Click me</button>
```